# cannot connect to bitbucket from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I try to connect to bitbucket from Jenkins.  I have Git plugin installed.  I kept getting the following error message. I tried 2 different repository URL, none of them are working.  Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes bitbucket repos are in Mercurial. Can you clone it from the command line?

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn, i am using Git, not Mercurial.

Comment: Possibly you need to set up the API  Tokens like this http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2014/02/05/integrating-bitbucket-and-jenkins/ then